# How can use the default function " toggleBoldface(sender: AnyObject>)" and toggleItalics(<sender: AnyObject>) in swift

Tags: swift, toggle, default, italic

I have two buttons Bold and italic.And 3 lables.Need to do normal bold and italic functionality.I done with manually using UIFont(name: "Helvetica-Oblique", size: 18).But it makes hard to me.

Is there any way to using the default funcions " toggleBoldface(sender: AnyObject>)" and "toggleItalics()".Please give me a demo.I read in apple document  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/toggleItalics:  But dont know how to proceed with events.

Comment: have you managed to find something regarding to this?

Comment: Yes i managed using other codes.But not with " toggleBoldface(sender: AnyObject>)".

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a UITextView, when you tap the bold button,  do the following thing.

```
@objc func boldButtonTapped() {
    textView.toggleBoldface(sender: nil)
}
```